# PDO will not run since upgrading PHP to 5.4.22

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I just recently upgraded my server's PHP version to 5.4.22, and now every script that uses PDO does not work.

An example of my PHP script which won't work:

```
<?php
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testDB;host=127.0.0.1';
    $user = '[hidden]';
    $password = '[hidden]';
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
?>
```

When i run the script i get: `Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found`, i get this same error for every script that creates a connection.

I ran a check on puTTY to check PDO was even there and it found this:

```
root@cpanel [~]# php -m | grep -i pdo
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
```

My **php.ini** has

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
; sqlite was removed by EasyApache v3.22.24 on Sat Dec 14 23:24:10 2013 (PHP v5.4.x incompatibility)
; extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

`phpinfo();` in PHP file claims im on `PHP Version 5.3.10`

How ever in my terminal `# php -v` says `PHP 5.4.22`

So this had really confused me why i'm getting two versions.

Comment: @JakeGould already read that question, didn't seem to help my situation =/

Comment: do you see the line extension=pdo.so enabled in php.ini ?

Comment: Well I see `extension=pdo.so` it doesn't have enabled written next to it but it is there.

Comment: I meant , is it starting with ; ?

Comment: @Satya no it is not. the only one that is with ; is `; extension=sqlite.so`

Comment: I've noticed PDO is not in my phpinfo(); i don't know if that narrows down the possible causes of my issue?

Comment: @JakeGould where did i say it did? I merely pointed out it was only one with a semi colon.

Comment: @JakeGould I checked `phpinfo();` in the PHP script it not only doesn't show `pdo` it shows my previous PHP version (which was the version that worked with my PDO at the time). Which is even more confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question shows that you are checking the PHP version via the command line. But PHP via a web browser is going to use a module loaded into Apache which is a completely different thing. So check the output of `phpinfo();` in a PHP script loaded via the web browser. Is PDO installed or shows as installed via that?

Wherever your Apache config files are look for the directory `mods-available` and the file `php5.load`. Under Ubuntu 12.04 it would be in this path:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load
```

And the contents should be:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

Does the path in that file match where the newly compiled `libphp5.so` is installed?

Also, that `LoadModule php5_module` line could be a part of your main Apache configuration.  Look around to find where that is set.  And then just set the path of the new module to me wherever it’s actually installed.